# Why does Nginx behave differently on Linux and Windows when an upstream server is unavailable?

Tags: linux, windows, nginx

I have configured Nginx 1.10.1 to proxy Tomcat. If Tomcat is not running, Nginx does the following:

- On Linux, immediately return a 502 Bad Gateway.
- On Windows, wait for 60 seconds, then return a 504 Gateway Timeout.

This is my Nginx config:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream tomcat_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8081;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://tomcat_server;
            proxy_redirect http://tomcat_server/ $scheme://$host:$server_port/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        }
    }
}
```

Using Curl to request a Tomcat resource immediately fails with essentially the same error on both Linux and Windows (there is no 60 second delay in this case):

```
# Windows:
> curl http://localhost:8080 -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

# Linux:
> curl -v http://127.107.177.129:8080
* About to connect() to 127.107.177.129 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.107.177.129... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

So why the difference in behaviour?

The timeout on Windows is governed by `proxy_connect_timeout` - if I reduce this to 1 second, I get the 502 error after 1 second instead of 60 seconds. Incidentally, I am also at a loss as to what exactly Nginx is doing in those 60 seconds - it doesn't appear to be retrying the connection because if I start Tomcat after 10 seconds it still times out 50 seconds later. It seems to be twiddling its thumbs.

Can anyone shed some light on either of these behaviours?

Comment: Do you have e.g. windows firewall running ?

Comment: @nos I don't think that is relevant. When Tomcat is running, everything works. When Tomcat is not running, the behaviours become different. The OS refuses the connection on both Linux and Windows in exactly the same way. How could the firewall affect anything?

Comment: Windows Firewall has the ability to automatically pass or drop traffic to ports based on which application is currently running/has registered itself with windows firewall - that is the reason I ask. You could always turn off the windows firewall service temporarily, and do a quick test to see if it is related. (or any other firewall product you might have running).

Comment: @nos Good point about process-based filtering. Disabling the firewall is worth a try.

Comment: @nos I tried disabling Windows firewall and anti-virus, and it had no effect.